# Nested case in SQL referring different fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested, case

I have a nested case loop in SQL where I'm checking it date is before 2016 then set status = 3, otherwise change status based on current status. I'm getting an error in the below code

```
case
  when x.myDate is not null and x.myDate < Convert(datetime, '2015-12-31') then x.myStatus = '3'
  else
     case 
      when x.myStatus = 1 then '2'
      when x.myStatus = 3 then '1'
      when x.myStatus = 2 then '3'
     else ''
     end
 end
```

> Error: Incorrect Syntax near '=' on 2nd line

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot so this `x.myStatus = '3'` in `CASE` statement `Then`. `Then` allows only valid *expression*.

> Expression is a combination of symbols and operators that the SQL
>   Server Database Engine evaluates to obtain a single data value. Simple expressions can be a single constant, variable, column, or scalar function. Operators can be used to join two or more simple expressions into a complex expression.

Here is the correct way

```
SELECT myStatus = CASE
                    WHEN x.myDate IS NOT NULL
                         AND x.myDate < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31') THEN '3'
                    ELSE
                      CASE x.myStatus
                        WHEN 1 THEN '2'
                        WHEN 3 THEN '1'
                        WHEN 2 THEN '3'
                        ELSE ''
                      END
                  END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set x.myStatus =
case when x.myDate is not null and x.myDate < Convert(datetime, '2015-12-31') then '3'
     when x.myStatus = 1 then '2'
     when x.myStatus = 3 then '1'
     when x.myStatus = 2 then '3'    
     else ''
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
when x.myDate is not null and x.myDate < Convert(datetime, '2015-12-31') then x.myStatus = '3'
```

to this:

```
when x.myDate is not null and x.myDate < Convert(datetime, '2015-12-31') then '3'
```